# Emacs set tab-stop-list only local to a buffer?

Tags: emacs

All projects I work with use 2 spaces for indent, so I have my tab-stop-list set as such. However, for a particular file extension, I need to use 4 spaces.

I'm trying to add a mode hook that does:

```
(setq tab-stop-list (number-sequence 4 200 4))
```

Which works, except it seems to affect all buffers, not just the current one. Is there any way to make this setting buffer-local?

Comment: Incidentally - nice to meet you here :-) I have a preliminary but usable emacs module in melpa using boris as comint backend process, and boris based php-completion on the way. Thanks!

Comment: @TomRegner that's awesome. I'd love to see how you go with that, and how you do it. I have plans to define a small protocol for Boris and more cleanly split the readline and eval worker parts of it, which should make such things *much* easier to do.

Comment: Well, it's my elisp learning playground, I keep it simple. Have a look, if you like: https://github.com/tomterl/company-php-session-backend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change that assigment to

```
(set (make-local-variable 'tab-stop-list) (number-sequence 4 200 4))
```

that should do it